# Get JSON from aspx URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am presently trying to get a json response from a url, so that I can load the JSON data into a spreadsheet.

This seems to work fine in the developer tools window of Chrome (if I view the XHR requests after changing the number of rows visible, I can see the json in full).

The problem is, I am not familiar with asp, so I can not work out the correct syntax for the url so that I can get this json directly.

You will see the xhr request if you go to http://zulutrade.com/TradeHistoryIndividual.aspx?pid=24508 and change the number of trades visible.

Could somebody possibly tell me how to structure the full url (i.e. so that it includes the request payload)?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I have tried using http://zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx/GetProviderTrades but this clearly does not work as I am unsure how to add the request data - I also tried http://zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx/GetProviderTrades?providerId=24508 but this resulted in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a webservice reference to create a service proxy class. This is done via the WSDL that the service returns.

Here is the proper url for that:

http://zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Thanks for the info - could you provide any pointers to a reference/tutorial on how to consume such a resource from a Google Docs spreadsheet?

Comment: link is dead please update the answer, or it should be down voted